# How to push key value of element to array_push using PHP

Tags: php, array-push

I have created empty array and want to push all values and its key to the new created array but I am getting error array_push() expects at least 2 parameters I know array_push needs two parameter and here I am passing only one but what I ant is all keys and values to be pushed directly to array

```
//   Here 'userid' is just text or can say sample key and 
 //  Here $userid is getting from table so expected output

 //   'userid'=>$userid

$temp = array();

  array_push($temp['userid'] = $userid);
```

Comment: Just use `$temp['userid'] = $userid;`

Answer (score 2):

To push to an array using a key - value pair, you do not need to use array_push.

array_push expects the array, and the value (no key) that you're pushing.

To push to an array using a key - value pair simply do :

```
$temp['user_id'] = $userid;
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `array_push` you must give it the original array (modified by reference) and the new entry (value) for it. In this case since you have a key as well, you'd need to merge your arrays:

```
$temp = array_merge($temp, ['userid' => $userid]);
```

However, you can use simple array syntax instead to achieve the same thing:

```
$temp = array();
$temp['userid'] = $userid;
```

Comment: but i  want use  array_push because I am pushing multiple values in post i have shown one value

Comment: I think you should look at `array_merge()` instead (see my example). You can pass it the post array and merge all of it in at once

Comment: Important to note that `array_push()` doesn't let you control keys, only values